# Dice outcome evaluation based on bias

Tags: python, function, numpy, random, return

I am trying to determine throw of dices on a bias condition, during implementing its code, i am facing this error (code and error):

```
from numpy import random 

def roll(N,bias):

'''will return the dice outcome'''
return random.choice(np.range(N),p=bias)

>>N= 50

>>bias= (0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.25)

>>roll(N,bias) # returns 50 outcomes of dice (1,3,4,5...)



Error:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-ac839882958b> in <module>
      1 N= 50
      2 bias= (0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.25)
----> 3 roll(N,bias)

<ipython-input-104-d4d7cbf35d08> in roll(N, bias)
      2 def roll(N,bias):
      3     '''will return the dice outcome'''
----> 4     return random.choice(np.range(N),p=bias)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    213             else:
    214                 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
--> 215                                      "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))
    216 
    217         def __dir__():

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'range'
```

The objective is to return a list of dice throw values based on bias.
Can you tell me what is wrong with the code here?

Comment: I guess u can paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really?

```
    return random.choice(np.arange(N),p=bias)
```

**Edit**
I misunderstood the requirement.  You want this to return the results of N rolls.

```
def roll(N,bias):
    return (random.choice(range(len(bias)),p=bias)+1 for _ in range(N))
```

Comment: What do u suggest?

Comment: That was it.  That's the fix.  You have `range`, when the actual numpy function is called `arange`.

Comment: Cool, however its saying that 'a' and 'p' must have the same value, in the return statement

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the code.  Let me modify my answer.

Comment: However, the resultant is a generator function, how could u see the values generated in a list or tuple?

Comment: You can use `list(roll(N,bias))`.   Or, if you want, you can do that as the return from the function, so it returns a list directly.

Comment: Getting a value error now: ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1

Comment: That's correct, they do not.  If you really need 5:4:3:3:2:5 ratio, then you'll have to change your fractions to add up to 1.  [.227, .182, .136, .136, .092, .227]